# unique values of one column for unique values of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, reshape

Consider following sample data frame.

```
> ww
  col1 col2
1    1    A
2    2    A
3    3    A
4    4    B
5    5    B
6    6    B
7    7    C
8    8    C
9    9    C
> dput(ww)
structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), col2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to know if each category of `col2` has different values in `col1` or not. In the end, I want to get an answer (TRUE or FALSE). TRUE (if all categories of `col2` have completely different sets of values in `col1`), and FALSE (if there exists atleast 2 categories in `col2` which have atleast 1 value in `col1` common.

For above example, answer is TRUE since categories A, B and C don't have any value of `col1` for them common. Values of `col1` are 1,2,3 for A. Values of `col1` are 4,5,6 for B. Values of `col1` are 7,8,9 for C.

I can try splitting data the data frame by `col2` and then saving values of `col1` for each member then check for common values using `intersect` but that is kind of lengthy and inefficient process for a large data frame. Can somebody provide me with an efficient solution? Any data table solution would also do.

Comment: You could used `duplicated` to see if there are duplicates. I'm assuming two rows of `1 A` followed by `1 A`  is the kind of condition you're looking for to create a false return. `duplicated` will return what values are duplicated (not including the original). Using it in conjunction with `any` could give you the functionality you are looking for if I am understanding.

Comment: Can the categories of `col2` have duplicate values in `col1`, ie., could category A have two 1s? If not, the @giraffehere suggestion is spot on. In fact, you'd want to use `anyDuplicated`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ww)[, un.col1 := uniqueN(col1)==.N, by = col2]
```

which gives:

```
> ww
   col1 col2 un.col1
1:    1    A   FALSE
2:    1    A   FALSE
3:    3    A   FALSE
4:    4    B    TRUE
5:    5    B    TRUE
6:    6    B    TRUE
7:    1    C    TRUE
8:    8    C    TRUE
9:    9    C    TRUE
```

Or as @giraffehere mentioned in the comments, a combination of `duplicated` and `any` with `anyDuplicated`:

```
setDT(ww)[, un.col1 := !anyDuplicated(col1), by = col2]
```

---

If you are looking for uniqueness between categories, as @MatthewPlourde suggested, then you can use:

```
setDT(ww)[, un.col2 := uniqueN(col2) > 1, by = col1]
```

which gives:

```
> ww
   col1 col2 un.col2
1:    1    A    TRUE
2:    1    A    TRUE
3:    3    A   FALSE
4:    4    B   FALSE
5:    5    B   FALSE
6:    6    B   FALSE
7:    1    C    TRUE
8:    8    C   FALSE
9:    9    C   FALSE
```

---

Used data:

```
ww <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9),
                     col2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")),
                .Names = c("col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what OP is looking for. As I understand it, he/she is looking for uniqueness between categories, not within.

Comment: Mathew is correct. I am looking for uniqueness between categories.

Comment: @Jaap, I believe OP wants one boolean indicating whether all the categories have their own unique set of values. (not my DV)

Comment: `setDT(ww)[, .(un = uniqueN(col2)), by=col1][, all(un == 1L)]` I think should work..

Comment: @akrun I'm not duping your posts because it's you.

Comment: @Jaap It's okay, but this seems to be a dupe.  If not, you can reopen it.

Comment: @akrun Why did you delete your comment? Afraid someone could read it?

Comment: @Jaap Not really.  I just deleted it because it was not a comment to your answer, but about the dupe.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the OP is that there should be a single TRUE/FALSE value for the entire data frame. Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

ww %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarise(ndis = n_distinct(col2)) %>%
  summarise(all(ndis == 1))
```

Comment: I think this is still missing the point. My reading of OP's post is that s/he wants to check for uniqueness between categories, not within.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde - my solution does check for uniqueness *between* categories.

Comment: I think OP just needs to clarify a little bit more about what he/she wants.

Answer (score 1):

If there can only be unique values within a category, then all you need is

```
anyDuplicated(ww$col1) == 0
```

If there can be duplicates within a category, remove them with

```
ww2 <- ww[!duplicated(interaction(ww$col1, ww$col2)), ]
```

Then use `anyDuplicated` on `col1`